# Timezone (CST6CDT) is not a known timezone Magento cannot login to admin

Tags: magento-1.9, admin, timezone

```
timezone (CST6CDT) is not a known timezone";i:1;s:3233:"#0
 \app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model\Locale.php(527):
 Zend_Date_DateObject->setTimezone('CST6CDT')
```

Cannot login to admin panel i get this exception. I also tried

```
/app/code/core/Mage/Reports/Model/Resource/Order/Collection.php
```

replacing line 373 and 374, with Etc/UTC to UTC but no luck. I'm running the site on wamp and my php version is 5.5.12. I want to fix the issue without downgrading php version to 5.4.

How can i change timezone (CST6CDT) to a valid timezone? (Note: I do not have access to the admin panel)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Managed to fix it as mentioned below

Open table `core_config_data` in the magento database and edit `general/locale/timezone` to `UTC` or any other valid timezone.